# Access report not updating after query change

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form, below, that allows the user to filter the database multiple ways. When they push the filter button on the form a report populates based on the filter query. The issue is if I filter the database again, even with `.requery` in the report code, the report doesn't update to the new Query results. I know if I manually close out of the report it works, however when I code it to `DoCmd.Close` it doesn't actually close the report. If I show it in 
`acViewPreview` it updates each time I use the refilter button on the form but then I cant use buttons on the report. I am trying to make it like a kiosk so I don't want the nav tabs to show.

**Filter form**

[image]

**Report**

[image]

**Form Code:**

```vb
Private Sub btnFilter_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim SQL2 As String
    Dim ToDate As Date
    Dim FromDate As Date

    SQL2 = ""

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Filter")

If cmbFilter.Value = "Vended Date" Then

    ToDate = Format(DTPickerTo.Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    FromDate = Format(DTPickerFrom.Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")

SQL2 = "SELECT CribMaster_Quality.Line,CribMaster_Quality.[Vended Date],CribMaster_Quality.PartNumber,CribMaster_Quality.Group,CribMaster_Quality.ItemNumber,CribMaster_Quality.Amount,CribMaster_Quality.Description,CribMaster_Quality.Cost,CribMaster_Quality.[Extended Cost],CribMaster_Quality.User " & _
        " FROM CribMaster_Quality" & _
        " WHERE CribMaster_Quality.[Vended Date]" & _
        " BETWEEN #" & FromDate & "# AND #" & ToDate & "#" & _
        " ORDER BY CribMaster_Quality.[Vended Date] DESC;"
ElseIf ckbDateConst = True Then

    ToDate = Format(DTPickerTo.Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    FromDate = Format(DTPickerFrom.Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")

    SQL2 = "SELECT CribMaster_Quality.Line,CribMaster_Quality.[Vended Date],CribMaster_Quality.PartNumber,CribMaster_Quality.Group,CribMaster_Quality.ItemNumber,CribMaster_Quality.Amount,CribMaster_Quality.Description,CribMaster_Quality.Cost,CribMaster_Quality.[Extended Cost],CribMaster_Quality.User " & _
        " FROM CribMaster_Quality" & _
        " WHERE CribMaster_Quality." & Me!cmbFilter.Value & " = '" & Me!cmbFilterBy.Value & "' And CribMaster_Quality.[Vended Date] " & _
        " BETWEEN #" & FromDate & "# AND #" & ToDate & "#" & _
        " ORDER BY " & Me.cmbFilter.Value & " DESC;"
    Else
    SQL2 = "SELECT CribMaster_Quality.Line,CribMaster_Quality.[Vended Date],CribMaster_Quality.PartNumber,CribMaster_Quality.Group,CribMaster_Quality.ItemNumber,CribMaster_Quality.Amount,CribMaster_Quality.Description,CribMaster_Quality.Cost,CribMaster_Quality.[Extended Cost],CribMaster_Quality.User " & _
            " FROM CribMaster_Quality" & _
            " WHERE CribMaster_Quality." & Me!cmbFilter.Value & " = '" & Me!cmbFilterBy.Value & "'" & _
            " ORDER BY " & Me.cmbFilter.Value & " DESC;"
    End If

    qdf.SQL = SQL2
    Set db = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing

    DoCmd.OpenReport "CribMasterReport", acViewReport
End Sub
```

**Report Code:**

```vb
Private Sub btnReFilter_Click()
    DoCmd.Close , acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Filter Database Form"
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Load()

Me.Requery

With VendedDatetxt
    .Requery
End With

With ItemNumbertxt
    .Requery
End With

With Linetxt
    .Requery
End With

With PartNumbertxt
    .Requery
End With

With Usertxt
    .Requery
End With

With Amounttxt
    .Requery
End With

With Costtxt
    .Requery
End With

With ExtendedCosttxt
    .Requery
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Access reports can be buggy and unintuitive in many different ways. If I were you, I'd requery on the main form (or intermediate form) and then call a fresh report. If you need results displayed before they select an option, show them on the intermediate form and put the buttons there. Anything to simplify your reports will save you a ton of headaches.

Comment: @abraxascarab How are Access reports buggy?

Comment: @abraxascarab  How do you call a fresh report besides what I am already using? `DoCmd.OpenReport`

Comment: @nicomp: Maybe I should have avoided the word 'buggy' and just stuck with the word 'unintuitive'.  When you try to push report functionality to the limits (which sometimes includes trying to use it as a form with buttons) it can be very difficult to find the proper way to get it to launch things in the right sequence.  This has to do with the 'unintuitive' way Access builds a report.  IMHO, it's easier to avoid the 'bugginess' by using report features to return just the report and to use forms for selection logic and controls.  With that said, yes you can build a report with complex logic.

Comment: @holi4683:  To me, your code looks like it is doing the refreshes *in* the report and it has control buttons on the report.  I'm suggesting an alternate route (of possibly less headaches) of displaying your report info on an intermediate form, put your selection buttons there, then do your refreshes there *before* you launch the report.  That way you send the report only the data it needs already refreshed.  (Your way can possibly work, but I've found Access reports to be complicated in the order it builds the report. Keeping it simple saves headaches.)

Comment: I completely agree with @abraxascarab.  Is the Report only for onscreen viewing, or is it intended to also be printed?  Depending on the requirement you could create subForms to replace the Report object, or you could use a subReport control on a form to show the report.  Then you could have buttons on the Form rather than on the Report itself, but be able to preview the report while still having buttons and other filter controls available at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

**Issue 1: Requerying the Report**

When a report is opened using standard techniques, such as clicking on a report in the Navigation pane or when opening a report using `DoCmd.OpenReport`, Access creates a *default instance* of the Report that is accessible via the `Application.Reports` collection.  Before the report is first opened or if the default report instance is completely closed (i.e. removed from memory), the `Application.Reports` collection will not contain an instance of the report.  Before accessing the default instance, ensure that the report is already open.

Like other MS Office object-model collections, `Application.Reports` does not have a "Contains" method or other direct way to test whether a report is already open, only by looping through numeric indexes and testing each report object.  Although it seems sloppy to me, the easiest method is to use error handling to try getting the report directly, then catching the error if it's not found:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set frm = Application.Reports("CribMasterReport")
If err.Number <> 0 Then
  'Default instance not open
End If
```

CAUTION: *Do not* refer to the report using the class name like an object, as in `Report_CribMasterReport.Requery`.  If you do that, VBA will automatically create a new, hidden instance of the report, but it is NOT the same default instance as described above and this new instance will not be accessible via the `Application.Reports` collection.  Likewise, using the properties and calling methods on such an object will be largely ineffective.  (It is possible to create and use such independent instances, but that is an advance technique riddled with its own pitfalls and challenges.)

As the question describes, which is also confirmed by other online sources, the `Report.Requery` is not effective in refreshing the report after the underlying query or data have changed.  However, resetting the `Report.RecordSource` forces a full refresh of the report when in normal Report View.

**Issue 2: Report not closing**

The DoCmd.Close command was missing a comma.  It should be `DoCmd.Close , , acSaveNo`.  Even better is to *always* use explicit names for optional parameters.  Typing an extra parameter is definitely worth the saved frustration and time with typos in an ambiguous list of commas:

```
DoCmd.Close Save:=acSaveNo
```

**Issue 3: Unnecessary calls**

It is completely unnecessary to call Requery on the report and every single control in the Report_Load event.  I get that you were trying to debug the situation, but this behavior should happen automatically.  Also, the Form_Load event occurs only once when the form is first loaded, so that code would not be called again unless the report is completely closed and reopened.

**Finally some alternative code**

```
Private Sub btnFilter_Click()
    '... Include previous code to reset report query

    '* Call DoCmd.OpenReport every time to
    '* 1) Ensure default report is open 
    '* 2) Automatically activate the report (even if it was already open)
    DoCmd.OpenReport "CribMasterReport", acViewReport

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim frm As Report_CribMasterReport
    Set frm = Application.Reports("CribMasterReport")
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        '* Force the Report object to re-run query and recreate report
        frm.RecordSource = frm.RecordSource
    End If
End Sub
```

It is no longer be necessary to completely close the report.

```
Private Sub btnReFilter_Click()
    ''DoCmd.Close Save:=acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Filter Database Form"
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Load()
    '* Eliminated unnecessary Requery calls
End Sub
```